# Не работает псевдокласс :checked у radio

Tags: css, css3, html5, html-form

При нажатии, у label должен меняться цвет фона, но селектор не срабатывает .modal__checkbox label input:checked + .modal__checkbox label

Вот код:

```css
.modal__checkbox{
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-around;
 align-items: center;
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 70%;
 border: 1px solid #bdbdbd;
 padding: 0px;
 border-radius: 15px;
 height: 45px;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.modal__checkbox label{
 margin-left: 0px;
 padding-top: 5px;
 font-size: 20px;
 margin-bottom: 0;
 cursor: pointer;
 position: relative;
 user-select: none;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}
.modal__checkbox label input{
 display: none;
}
.modal__checkbox label span{
 display: block;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
.modal__checkbox label i{
 font-size: 20px;
 margin-left: 5px;
}
.modal__checkbox .fa-whatsapp{
 color: #29d166;
}
.modal__checkbox .fa-viber{
 color: #7f40bd;
}
.modal__checkbox label input:checked + .modal__checkbox label{
 background-color: #f7ce68;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal__checkbox">
 <label><input type="radio" name="messenger" value="email" checked>Email<i class="far fa-envelope"></i></label>
 <label><input type="radio" name="messenger" value="WhatsApp"><span>WhatsApp<i class="fab fa-whatsapp"></i></span></label>
 <label><input type="radio" name="messenger" value="Viber"><span>Viber<i class="fab fa-viber"></i></span></label>
</div>
```

Comment: Нет, не должен.

Comment: Хотелось бы услышать более развернутый ответ

Comment: `+` обозначает соседа справа, но в вашем html-коде справа от `input` находятся `span` и `i`, а никакого `.modal__checkbox` справа нет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваш стиль не сработает, и не должен работать.
Ибо конструкция:

```
.modal__checkbox label input:checked + .modal__checkbox label{
    background-color: #f7ce68;
}
```

в переводе с машинного на русский читается так:

```
применить стиль к элементу label, 
вложенному в .modal__checkbox, 
который находится сразу после input:checked,
который вложен в label, вложенный в .modal__checkbox
```

ваш HTML не содержит такой конструкции.

Вам надо:

- Либо изменить HTML и CSS так, как показано в предыдущем ответе
- Либо вынести чекбоксы ПЕРЕД лейблами (все равно они скрыты с помощью `display:none`) - тогда сработает нормальный стиль `input:checked + label {background...}`

Рекомендую второй вариант, ибо вставлять чекбокс внутрь его лейбла - свинство и анти-феншуй. Так делают ленивые мракобесы, либо несчастные грешники, вынужденные работать в условиях, когда чекбоксам невозможно задать `id`.

А чтобы клик по лейблу менял состояние чекбокса, можно (И НУЖНО) использовать атрибут `for`.

Answer (score 0):

```
.modal__checkbox label input:checked + span {
```

```css
.modal__checkbox {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 70%;
  border: 1px solid #bdbdbd;
  padding: 0px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  height: 45px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.modal__checkbox label {
  margin-left: 0px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  user-select: none;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.modal__checkbox label input {
  display: none;
}

.modal__checkbox label span {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.modal__checkbox label i {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.modal__checkbox .fa-whatsapp {
  color: #29d166;
}

.modal__checkbox .fa-viber {
  color: #7f40bd;
}

.modal__checkbox label input:checked + span {
  background-color: #f7ce68;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal__checkbox">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="messenger" value="email" checked/>
    <span>Email<i class="far fa-envelope"></i></span>
  </label>
  
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="messenger" value="WhatsApp"/>
    <span>WhatsApp<i class="fab fa-whatsapp"></i></span>
  </label>
  
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="messenger" value="Viber"/>
    <span>Viber<i class="fab fa-viber"></i></span>
  </label>
</div>
```